# Sign up and sign in system with netsqlazman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, netsqlazman

Unfortunately, I have been forced to use netsqlazman in a project. After a long time searching I found nothing and I was wondering if there is any way or a tutorial or sample code to implement authentication (sign in and sign up) system with netsqlazman.

Before netsqlazman, I was using identity and JWT tokens for authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetSqlAzMan was intended for storage and retrieval of **authorization** information, not authentication. It does not provide sign in and sign up mechanisms at all.

You can continue using any identity system, as long as it hands out Windows identities (NetSqlAzMan stores Windows user [SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier)).